# Adobe AIR popup error when trying to run League of Legends

Tags: 14.04, playonlinux, adobe-air

I installed League of Legends-based tutorials, but I'm still getting this error. Could anyone help me?

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

[image]

9500 GT Video Card, Drive 331.38

This is written in the image

This application requires a version of Adobe AIR which can not be found.
Download the latest version of the runtime at adobe.com / go / getair_br 
or contact the application author for an updated version

Comment: Could you add more details please ? Which video card are you using ? which driver ? also, can you provide us with an English translated version of this error please ?

Comment: This happens when I go to POL>Configure>Install Components > directX9(for my situation),this error showed up after I installed something. No solutions so far.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Wine AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19141&iTestingId=83667), LoL throws a few errors but does eventually run with minimal problems. Try just clicking through the errors. (take screenshots for reference in case it doesn't work)

Comment: So wanted a solution to this problem of Adobe Air, that I've seen several tutorials on how to pop lol none of this problem as more tidy Adobe air 
Thanks for that would help

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you're using POL or Wine,  I've had *slightly* better luck by using POL instead of just wine and using the latest version of `playonlinux` from the website (not from the apt-get repo).

In PlayOnLinux Search under Games (Testing checkbox must be on)